# How to open accordion when setting error?

Tags: 8, forms

I have custom validation on an element using ['#element_validate'].

But the element is within an accordion item within an accordion and the error doesn't signal to the parent elements to open up when the form is reloaded with the errors.

Is there a way to signal to an elements groups to open up when doing `$form_state->setError($element)` on an element?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean vertical tabs? https://gist.github.com/ivanjaros/90b5ad9822a7f824cd1b90b426ab4045

Comment: They are part of the field_group module.  They are literally called "Accordion item", but they behave similar to vertical tabs.  I have added a screenshot of the config drop down from the form display config.  It has different css from vertical tabs: "required-fields field-group-accordion-item field-group-format-wrapper ui-accordion-content ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-accordion-content-active"

Answer (score 1):

I have added this an issue on the field_group module and have posted a patch: https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group/issues/2923831